# Getting predictions after training using darknet

Tags: opencv, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am new to CNN, I'm trying to train a classifier using [CIFAR-10](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~kriz/cifar.html) dataset. I follow [Pjreddie's Tutorial](https://pjreddie.com/darknet/train-cifar/) to train a simple classifier of 10 class dataset .

I trained the model using the code below, i got `cifar_small.weights` which i later used for detection

```
./darknet classifier train cfg/cifar.data cfg/cifar_small.cfg
```

after training the simple network,i try to detect using `cifar_small.cfg` and `cifar_small.weigths`

```
./darknet detect cfg/cifar_small.cfg cifar_small.weights data/dog.jpg
```

> layer     filters    size              input                output
>       0 conv     32  3 x 3 / 1    28 x  28 x   3   ->    28 x  28 x  32
>       1 max          2 x 2 / 2    28 x  28 x  32   ->    14 x  14 x  32
>       2 conv     64  3 x 3 / 1    14 x  14 x  32   ->    14 x  14 x  64
>       3 max          2 x 2 / 2    14 x  14 x  64   ->     7 x   7 x  64
>       4 conv    128  3 x 3 / 1     7 x   7 x  64   ->     7 x   7 x 128
>       5 conv     10  1 x 1 / 1     7 x   7 x 128   ->     7 x   7 x  10
>       6 avg                        7 x   7 x  10   ->    10
>       7 softmax                                          10
>       8 cost                                             10 Loading weights
>  from cifar_small.weights...Done!
>  data/dog.jpg: Predicted in
>   0.007035 seconds.
>  Not compiled with OpenCV, saving to predictions.png instead

It does not predict the values in the terminal and does not draw bounding box on output image. The output of the image is same as the input.
 
When i try prediction for the same image with `yolo.cfg` and pre-trained `yolo.weights`, it works as shown below.

> layer     filters    size              input                output
>       0 conv     32  3 x 3 / 1   416 x 416 x   3   ->   416 x 416 x  32
>       1 max          2 x 2 / 2   416 x 416 x  32   ->   208 x 208 x  32
>       2 conv     64  3 x 3 / 1   208 x 208 x  32   ->   208 x 208 x  64
>       3 max          2 x 2 / 2   208 x 208 x  64   ->   104 x 104 x  64
>       4 conv    128  3 x 3 / 1   104 x 104 x  64   ->   104 x 104 x 128
>       5 conv     64  1 x 1 / 1   104 x 104 x 128   ->   104 x 104 x  64
>       6 conv    128  3 x 3 / 1   104 x 104 x  64   ->   104 x 104 x 128
>       7 max          2 x 2 / 2   104 x 104 x 128   ->    52 x  52 x 128
>       8 conv    256  3 x 3 / 1    52 x  52 x 128   ->    52 x  52 x 256
>       9 conv    128  1 x 1 / 1    52 x  52 x 256   ->    52 x  52 x 128
>     10 conv    256  3 x 3 / 1    52 x  52 x 128   ->    52 x 
>   52 x 256
>     11 max          2 x 2 / 2    52 x  52 x 256   ->    26
>   x  26 x 256
>     12 conv    512  3 x 3 / 1    26 x  26 x 256   ->
>   26 x  26 x 512
>     13 conv    256  1 x 1 / 1    26 x  26 x 512   ->
>   26 x  26 x 256
>     14 conv    512  3 x 3 / 1    26 x  26 x 256   ->
>   26 x  26 x 512
>     15 conv    256  1 x 1 / 1    26 x  26 x 512   ->
>   26 x  26 x 256
>     16 conv    512  3 x 3 / 1    26 x  26 x 256   ->
>   26 x  26 x 512
>     17 max          2 x 2 / 2    26 x  26 x 512   ->
>   13 x  13 x 512
>     18 conv   1024  3 x 3 / 1    13 x  13 x 512   ->
>   13 x  13 x1024
>     19 conv    512  1 x 1 / 1    13 x  13 x1024   ->
>   13 x  13 x 512
>     20 conv   1024  3 x 3 / 1    13 x  13 x 512   ->
>   13 x  13 x1024
>     21 conv    512  1 x 1 / 1    13 x  13 x1024   ->
>   13 x  13 x 512
>     22 conv   1024  3 x 3 / 1    13 x  13 x 512   ->
>   13 x  13 x1024
>     23 conv   1024  3 x 3 / 1    13 x  13 x1024   ->
>   13 x  13 x1024
>     24 conv   1024  3 x 3 / 1    13 x  13 x1024   ->
>   13 x  13 x1024
>     25 route  16
>     26 reorg              / 2
>   26 x  26 x 512   ->    13 x  13 x2048
>     27 route  26 24
>     28
>   conv   1024  3 x 3 / 1    13 x  13 x3072   ->    13 x  13 x1024
>   29 conv    425  1 x 1 / 1    13 x  13 x1024   ->    13 x  13 x 425
>   30 detection
>  Loading weights from yolo.weights...Done!
>   data/dog.jpg: Predicted in 11.057513 seconds.
>  car: 54%
>   bicycle: 51%
>  dog: 56%

it predicts as expected along with a bounding box in the output image.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use this command:

```
./darknet classify cfg/cifar_small.cfg cifar_small.weights data/dog.jpg
```

Check here: https://pjreddie.com/darknet/tiny-darknet/

Answer (score 0):

In the /examples/darknet.c (from line 422~500) you can see what the darknet framework does for every function input after the './darknet'.
In this case, '/.darknet classify ~' makes the function 'predict_classifier' run in examples/classifier.c run.

The prediction results are printed by the part from line 601~606 (in classifier.c)

```
for(i = 0; i < top; ++i)
{
    int index = indexes[i];
    printf("%5.2f%%: %s\n", predictions[index] * 100, names[index]);
}
```